# If I register a domain, can i link other things to it or will I need to pay for hosting?

Tags: website, domain

I was gonna get a domain name, but I've no idea about what happens once you buy one. Will I be able to point another site to it, or are they probably going to try get you to buy their hosting too?

Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

I got a feeling that is is not clear to you what a domain name is, so lets do this with something not computer related.

If I have a phone and I want people to reach me, then there are three parts:

1. I need to have a phone number of my own.
2. I need something to direct the call to my phone when that number is dailed.
3. I need to have a phone and answer it.

For hosting/domain names you have:

1. Just the domain name of your own.  (This is buying the domain name)
2. A way to point people to you (DNS)
3. A server answering requests (Your computer/VPS/hosting/...)

If you buy just a domain name then nothing happens. You just own (rent) the rights to that name.

Comment: Sorry, but you appear to think you must own a website to point a domain at it, which as far as I know is not true.

Comment: Not a website.  But you get a domain to point it at something. Usually a website, but that server can do a lot of other things. E.g. own hobby machine, or email server, gameserver, backup place, ... or a combination of all of them. I think it will come down to a server hosting webpages for 90% of the people reading this though.

Answer (score 1):

If you buy a domain, you can do whatever you want to with it. You will not need to buy hosting, unless its a package deal that you're paying for.

You can use an 'A Record' to point the domain to an IP of another system that is hosting a website for example.